# Would like to sample 14.04 before committing to it

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, dvd

Would like to sample Ubuntu 14.04 before committing to it. Presently running Ubuntu 12.04. Have burned a DVD with Ubuntu 14.04. How can I run from this DVD?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your `Bios Settings` and change to boot from the DVD.
If you don't know how to go to your `Bios` turn off your computer.After turning on your computer press <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>(most common).Usually there is a note indicating what button to press to go into your `Bios`.After you boot from the DVD you will see some options.Choose `Try Ubuntu`.

Comment: And choose 'Try Ubuntu'

Comment: Also please tell us what pc you are using.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the CD/DVD version is terribly slow to boot or install from.

I recommend you go to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS to create a bootable flash drive.  The reason I chose this method is it is extremely quick and easy to do from Windows.  Since you already use 12, you may know how to burn the image from Ubuntu.

In your computer BIOS, set the order of boot devices to 
 1. USB
 2. Hard Drives
etc.

At this time, I regret having moved from 12.04LTS to 14.04LTS.  14.04 freezes up often and seems to bog down quickly.  I find myself booting several times a day just to keep operational.  About the only time I rebooted 12.04 was when it was required by the updates.

Other than that, I have not seen any significant differences between 12 and 14.

I have started giving consideration to reverting back to 12.04 LTS.

Comment: I would recommend going only one step at a time (12.04->13.04->14.04). Especially in case of hardware that might be marginal.